# Multiple conditions in jquery ternary conditional operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I want to write ternary conditional operator in jquery where condition set by jquery variable. My script toggle's class for particular condition only.In my script variable comes from other settings.

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_div")
    .removeClass("horizontal vertical")
    .addClass( my_color == 'red'  ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
});
</script>
```

`my_color` is jquery variable which may have one value at a time from `red,green,blue,black,white or silver`.

I want to set class horizontal if `my_color` is red, blue or green and class vertical for other three values. can anyone help me write simplified ternary operator for above jquery?

Comment: IMO this is already simple and readable. I see no reason to refactor your ternary

Comment: But this is set for one condition my_color == 'red' only.

Comment: FYI: you are writing JavaScript ternary operators, not jQuery. jQuery is library written in JavaScript. jQuery is not a language.

Comment: thanks @Jan for your valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use or operator in the condition part of the operator. You your would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_div")
        .removeClass("horizontal vertical")
        .addClass( my_color == 'red' ||  my_color == 'blue' ||  my_color == 'green'  ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
  });
</script>
 $("#my_div")
```

If you have many color you can put them array and use that in condition.

```
 $("#my_div")
 .removeClass("horizontal vertical")
 .addClass( ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'].indexOf(my_color) != -1 ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. Is this good practice to write like yours one.

Comment: my_color is set of 6 values, so I think its easy to write like yours.

Comment: A possible change to your answer could be to use $.inArray, rather than multiple `or` statements. i.e. `addClass($.inArray(my_color, ['red', 'blue', 'green']) ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical')` which makes it a lot easier to add more colours if you want.

Comment: @gavin -I don't know why this doesn't work for me , and even for value red i am getting vertical. script working perfect with adils answer.

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault... `addClass($.inArray(my_color, ['red', 'blue', 'green']) !== -1 ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical')` - I keep on forgetting that `$.inArray` returns the position, rather than a boolean value. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/XRuf5/

Comment: Thanks Gavin, so nice of you, I could not participate in discussion because of some problem with internet, sorry about that, I updated my answer though.

Comment: Thanks  @Gavin /@Adil for yours contribution .yours answers are the better ans for my case.

Comment: And How can I do with the same if I have to shuffle css rule only , like float:left to float:none for list item "#my_div li"?